# MathJax doesn't convert \bf

Tags: mathjax

here is my JS part

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
MathJax.Hub.Config({
    displayAlign: "center",
    extensions: ["tex2jax.js"],
    menuSettings: {
        zoom: "Click",
        CTRL: false,
        ALT: false,
        CMD: false,
        Shift: false,
        zscale: "250%",
        font: "Auto",
        context: "MathJax",
        mpContext: false,
        mpMouse: false,
        texHints: true
    },
    TeX: {
        Macros: {
          RR: '{\\bf R}',
          bold: ['{\\bf #1}', 1]
        }
    },
    errorSettings: {
        message: ["[", ["MathProcessingError", "Math Processing Error"], "]"],
        style: {
            color: "#CC0000",
            "font-style": "italic"
        }
    },
    jax: ["input/TeX", "output/SVG"],
    tex2jax: {
        inlineMath: [
            ['$', '$'],
            ['\\(', '\\)']
        ],
        displayMath: [
            ['$$', '$$'],
            ['\\[', '\\]']
        ],
        preview: ["[math]"],
        processEscapes: true
    },
    "SVG": {
        blacker: 10,
        font: "TeX",
        scale: 100,

    },
    MathMenu: {
        delay: 150,
        helpURL: "http://www.mathjax.org/help-v2/user/",
        showRenderer: true,
        showMathPlayer: true,
        showFontMenu: true,
        showContext: false,
        showDiscoverable: true,
    }
});
</script>
```

as you could see, I already put there that part with **Tex** and **Macros** and also with **\bf**. Here is my displaying text

```
<p>
Nachr. {\bf 28} (1964), 1--43.
</p>
```

but it doesn't parse that part with \bf. Of course, when I have another latex parts in the text, it converts without problems, just this is problem to convert \bf to particular output.

Any help? Thanks

Comment: Although MathJax uses a similar syntax as LaTeX, your question is most likely off-topic. Welcome to TeX.SX! anyway

Comment: As Christian says, I think [so] is a better place for this question.

Comment: I agree with @ChristianHupfer, MathJax is off topic here. However, isn't the MathJax' mission to handle the math syntax on web pages. `{\bf 28}` is not math mode, thus of course not handled by MathJax